# Prove subset equivalence

Tags: vector-spaces

Given $A,B$ and $C$ are subspace to a vector space $T$ over $\mathbb{R}$

If $A\subset T$ then show

$A\cap T=A$

Comment: If you are not sure, you should try to prove it anyway! Make it old school: take an element from the left-hand side and show that it is in the right-hand side. And vice versa.

Comment: Is there a typo in your title?  It looks like the RHS is a duplicate of the LHS.

Comment: Your proof is wrong because $(X\cap Z)+(Y\cap Z)=(X+Y)\cap Z$ is false in general. For instance, if $V = \mathbb R^2$ and $X,Y,Z$ are three different lines through the origin, then $X \cap Z = Y \cap Z = \{0\}$ but $(X+Y)\cap Z = Z$ since $X+Y=V$.

Anyway, $(X\cap Z)+(Y\cap Z)=(X+Y)\cap Z$ is true if $X \subseteq Z$ or $Y \subseteq Z$ (in which case the equation can be written as $X+(Y\cap Z)=(X+Y)\cap Z$ or $(X\cap Z)+Y=(X+Y)\cap Z$, respectively).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is $ (X \cap Z) + (Y \cap Z)$ equal to $(X + Y) \cap Z$? Did you try it before? Because otherwise you would have to prove it.

$\Rightarrow )$ We know that $X = X \cap Z$ because $X \subset Z$ so
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& X= X\cap Z \subset X \ \ \ \mbox{and} \ \ \ Y \cap Z \subset Y \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ X+(Y \cap Z) \subset X+Y \\
& X= X\cap Z \subset Z \ \ \ \mbox{and} \ \ \ Y \cap Z \subset Z \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ X+(Y \cap Z) \subset Z
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
then $X + (Y \cap Z) \subset (X+Y)\cap Z$.

$\Leftarrow )$ Let $a \in (X+Y)\cap Z$ then $a \in Z$ and $a\in X+Y$ so exist $x\in X, y\in Y$ such that $a = x+y$. Remember that $X \subset Z$ then $x \in Z$. Since $Z$ is a vector subspace it follows
\begin{equation}
y = x+y - x = a - x \in Z 
\end{equation}
Hence $y \in Y \cap Z$, *i. e.*, $a = x+y \in X+ (Y\cap Z)$.